# Tableau - Count Items in a Dimension based on what month they fall into

Tags: data-visualization, visualization, tableau-api

I am a newbie at Tableau (thought I have spent years working in R and Python), seems to be different in the way it handles things or I'm just not thinking the right way.

I have a data sources with training data (employees training and the status). The point is to build a dashboard that shows the % of training that is overdue. I have all of the logic for it, but I am stuck on something.

I have a calculated field to show me the total training due, then when I put that in a table, with a filter by year and a breakdown by month, I get the totals by month - good deal.

Now, I need to perform an year calculation (not the months, but the year based on a few different things), so my first step is I need to get the "Total Training Due" for December 2018. I have a dimension called "Due Month" which is a numeric (1,2,3,4, etc.) representing the month. So, based on what I have observed, I just need to do a little IF statement like so (keep in mind this is only for 2018 data right now):

```
IF [Due Month] = MAX[Due Month] THEN COUNT[Employee ID] END
```

I know this isn't the exact context, but it's sort of what I am looking for. So, for 2018, it would mean that, for all rows that are of month 12, I want to count those up (each row is a unique training requirement) and I want the total for the latest month in the data set. My overall goal is to create the calculation I need in a new sheet with a single calculated field (See the image below of the Excel spreadsheet and the J10 calculation). Then I can use a dashboard to combine everything. I thought about a total row at the bottom, but there isn't enough ways to change the totals to customize it to what I need. I figured I dashboard was the way to go and replicate each part it its own sheet.

I have seen so many suggestion for things like this, but not exactly this. I have tried many, but nothing that works. Here is the spreadsheet I am trying to replicate:

[image: Spreadsheet]

As you can see that calculation in J10 is kind of weird, no biggie for Excel, but I am struggling to replicate this in Tableau. Here is what I have in my Tableau so far, I'm 90% of the way there, I just need that last calculation. I have replicated the main table, and figure I'll do this J10 calc on a new sheet and just put them together on a Dahsboard. The only thing is, I want this to work when new data comes in, so I don't want to hard code any month numbers in there, I want it to be dynamic. Here is what I have on the tableau so far:

[image: Tableau]

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for this - after posting this, I was able to come up with this:

`(TOTAL([Incomplete Overdue]) + SUM(IF ([Past Due]<0 AND INT([Due Month]) = {MAX(INT([Due Month]))}) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) / COUNT(IF INT([Due Month]) = {MAX(INT([Due Month]))} THEN [Employee ID] END)`

Which works for the basic result I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value in Tableau that you have in F11 it's:

```
{FIXED [Due Year] : sum([Incomplete Overdue])}
```

You should be able to create that as another calculated field and then reference it, or include it directly in the Total Past Due Rate calculation.

This is an LOD calculation, the [Due Year] means that you only want the result dimensioned by the [Due Year] dimension, so you will get a different result for each year in the data source.

Comment: Thanks for this - after posting this, I was able to come up with this: `(TOTAL([Incomplete Overdue])
+ SUM(IF ([Past Due]<0 AND INT([Due Month]) = {MAX(INT([Due Month]))}) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
/ COUNT(IF INT([Due Month]) = {MAX(INT([Due Month]))} THEN [Employee ID] END)` This works, is your suggestion above more efficient than what I have?

Comment: You don't any Year testing.  Your calculation might be adding each month (eg January) of each year together

Comment: I have a filter for the year so that only 1 year is presented at a time. I tested this and it seems to work for the year comparing it to my manual results :)